# Loop function between columns by two [R]

Tags: r, loops, euclidean-distance

I am trying to calculate the distance (`df$X_Lambert_72_m`; `df$Y_Lambert_72_m`) of a individual over the different dates. In other words, the difference of position for B150 between `df$date` "1" & "2", "2" & "3", "3" & "4",...

Here I have the code to calculate the euclidian distance (`df$X_Lambert_72_m`; `df$Y_Lambert_72_m`) and between two dates

```
euclid <- function(x1, y1, x2, y2) { #Lambert already in cartesian meters
  sqrt( (x1-x2)^2 + (y1-y2)^2 )
}
df1 <- df %>%
  select(ID, contains("Lambert"), date) %>%
  pivot_wider(
    id_cols = ID,
    names_from = date,
    values_from = contains("Lambert")
  ) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(Dist1 = euclid(X_Lambert_72_m_1, Y_Lambert_72_m_1, 
                       X_Lambert_72_m_2, Y_Lambert_72_m_2)) %>%
  select(ID, Dist1)

df <- df %>% left_join(df1, by = "ID")
```

And I would like to loop the euclidian function but from dates "1"-"2" to dates n - n+1

Here is the dataset:

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c("B150", "B145", "B140", "B136", "B150", 
"B145", "B140", "B136", "B150", "B145", "B140", "B136", "B150", 
"B145", "B140", "B136"), Ellipsoid_height_m = c(155.5, 155.5, 
155.4, 155.3, 155.5, 155.5, 155.4, 155.3, 155.5, 155.5, 155.4, 
155.3, 155.5, 155.5, 155.4, 155.3), X_Lambert_72_m = c(232764.455, 
232765.271, 232766.444, 232767.093, 232766.955, 232767.771, 232768.944, 
232769.593, 232767.455, 232768.271, 232769.444, 232770.093, 232768.455, 
232769.271, 232770.444, 232771.093), Y_Lambert_72_m = c(125994.937, 
125996.489, 125997.991, 125998.854, 125994.937, 125996.489, 125997.991, 
125998.854, 125994.937, 125996.489, 125997.991, 125998.854, 125994.937, 
125996.489, 125997.991, 125998.854), Type = c("Pittag", "Pittag", 
"Pittag", "Pittag", "Pittag", "Pittag", "Pittag", "Pittag", "Pittag", 
"Pittag", "Pittag", "Pittag", "Pittag", "Pittag", "Pittag", "Pittag"
), date = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4"), class = "factor")), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -16L))
```

Comment: The distance is between `df$X_Lambert_72_m` & `df$Y_Lambert_72_m` and `date` correspond to the groups. I have edited my question to make it clearer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you want something like this. You are really just grouping by ID and then calculating the distance using `lead`. Based on your example, I assume you want to always compare the current date to the next date. If you want to compare the current date to the last date, switch `lead` to `lag`. Also you can set the default for when there is no lead or lag term. Right now, it is NA.

```r
library(tidyverse)

euclid <- function(x, y) { 
  sqrt( (x-lead(x))^2 + (y-lead(y))^2 )
}

df |>
  arrange(ID,date) |>
  group_by(ID) |>
  mutate(Dist1 = euclid(X_Lambert_72_m,Y_Lambert_72_m ))
#> # A tibble: 16 x 7
#> # Groups:   ID [4]
#>    ID    Ellipsoid_height_m X_Lambert_72_m Y_Lambert_72_m Type   date  Dist1
#>    <chr>              <dbl>          <dbl>          <dbl> <chr>  <fct> <dbl>
#>  1 B136                155.        232767.        125999. Pittag 1       2.5
#>  2 B136                155.        232770.        125999. Pittag 2       0.5
#>  3 B136                155.        232770.        125999. Pittag 3       1  
#>  4 B136                155.        232771.        125999. Pittag 4      NA  
#>  5 B140                155.        232766.        125998. Pittag 1       2.5
#>  6 B140                155.        232769.        125998. Pittag 2       0.5
#>  7 B140                155.        232769.        125998. Pittag 3       1  
#>  8 B140                155.        232770.        125998. Pittag 4      NA  
#>  9 B145                156.        232765.        125996. Pittag 1       2.5
#> 10 B145                156.        232768.        125996. Pittag 2       0.5
#> 11 B145                156.        232768.        125996. Pittag 3       1  
#> 12 B145                156.        232769.        125996. Pittag 4      NA  
#> 13 B150                156.        232764.        125995. Pittag 1       2.5
#> 14 B150                156.        232767.        125995. Pittag 2       0.5
#> 15 B150                156.        232767.        125995. Pittag 3       1  
#> 16 B150                156.        232768.        125995. Pittag 4      NA
```

Comment: I have added `mutate(Dist1 = ifelse(date == Date_max,sum(Dist1, na.rm = TRUE),Dist1))` at the end of the code. Like that I have the total for the final date. with `Date_max` obtained with the following code: 

`Date_max = df$date`
`Date_max = as.numeric(Date_max) `
`Date_max = max(Date_max)`
`Date_max = as.character(Date_max)`